# How to create an array containing the value of <td> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have a HTML structure like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Jack</td>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Barmar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now I'm trying to create a JS-array of all those names. I want something like this:

```
var Names = ["Jack", "Peter", "Barmar"];
```

---

Actually I can select those names using [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/fQ8iU5/1):

```
/\<td\>(.*)\<\/td\>/g
```

But I don't know how can I extract them from HTML and create a JS-array containing them. How can I do that?

Comment: `var Names = $('td').map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**with jQuery**

`var Names = $('td').map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();`

**with JavaScript**

```
var Names = [], tdEls = document.getElementsByTagName('td'),

for (var i = 0; i < tdEls.length; i++) {
  Names.push( tdEls[i].innerHTML );
}
```

**[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nLep9zwv/)**

Comment: This is really great! What if I wanted to take it a step further and make an array of each row, to be contained within the larger array? In other words, Names = [ [row1] , [row2] . . . ]
I'll need another loop... how will that work? For the rows, I'll also need maybe tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr') [0]; right? Then what will I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = $('td').map(function() {
   return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/4qwzpx52/8/)

The map function returns a jQuery collection which doesn't have a join function. You need to first convert it to a standard array, using the [get](http://api.jquery.com/get/) function.